# Why ajax doesn't work unless I refresh or use location.href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova, html-lists

I am working on a html project, which will eventually package by Phonegap. So I am trying to encode the data from html form to JSON format, then use ajax send to a php file resides on server, and receive the response to do something else.

Now I use `<a href='login.html'>` in my index.html to open the login page. In my login page, I have this

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(e) {                
            $('#loginform').submit(function(){
                var jData = { "email": $('#emailLogin').val(), "password": $('#Password').val()};

                $.ajax({                                      
                  url: 'PHP/login.php',
                  type:'POST',                           
                  data: jData,                                          
                  dataType: 'json',
                  async: false,
                  error: function(xhr,status){
                        //reload();
                        location.href='index.html';
                        alert('Wrong email and password');
                  },
                  success: function(data){
                      if(data[1] == 1){
                          var Id_user = data[0];
                          location.href='loginSuccess.html';
                      }
                  }
                }); 
            });
        });
    </script>
```

to send my data to server. But I found that it won't work, it's still in the login page. I tried to enter data and submit again, it's still nothing happen. Until I refresh the login page and enter data again, it can give an error message or go to the loginsuccess page. However, when I use `<script>
        function loadLogin(){
            location.href='login.html';
        } </script>` to open the login page, everything works well.

So what cause this? How can I modify this piece of code to make it better?

Comment: What do you mean by it won't work? Does the ajax request falls back to the error function? Does the request doesn't get fired at all? Isn't the form data sent in the request? What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the question.  You say you go to the page and nothing happens, then you hit refresh and then (and only then) does the ajax run?

Comment: @Delta I think it's not fired at all, because after I click submit, nothing happened and it's still in the login page without any error message.

Comment: @Dan Yeah, you're right. When I go to login page from the index, whatever I did, nothing happens. But if and only if I refresh, the login page will give me error message or lead me to another page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using jquery mobile？

I had encountered the same problem.

jQuery mobile has a global configuration option: ajaxEnabled, the default value is true.

it will automatically handle link clicks and form submissions through Ajax.

I think you can set false to load urls as regular http requests.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).bind('mobileinit', function() {
        $.extend($.mobile, {
            ajaxEnabled: false
        });
    });
</script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

Hope to help you.

Comment: I tried your method, but it still does not work. I still have to reload the page, then it will work for only one time.